# Click a rails link_to with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm trying to click a rails ajax link using jquery by clicking on a google map marker but can't figure out how to do it. Here's the link :

`sidelistings div`

```
<% @properties.each_with_index do |property,index| %>
          <div class="sidelisting" id="<%= index %>">
            <div><%= link_to image_tag("http://432.mlsimages.movoto.com/0#{property.mls.last(2)}/tn/#{property.mls}_0.jpg"), {:action => 'show', :id => property.id}, :remote => true %>  </div>
```

I have a google map with 20 markers on it which match the 20 properties in the above `sidelistings` div. I want to be able to click on the map marker and that will click the above link for it's corresponding property. I have made the `id`s of the 20 sidelistings match the indexes of the array of map markers. Here's my attempt at the jquery in the google maps code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerArray[i], 'click', function(){
         var element = this.id;
         var sidelisting = document.getElementById(element);
         $('sidelisting:a').click();
     });
```

The above code doesn't throw any errors in the console but clicking on the map marker does nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you put `console.log('in listener')` inside listener to check if it is being executed? I did not get in your question if you already checked that

Comment: I added that line to the end and each time I click on a map marker the console prints out: in listener. I think I'm just getting the syntax wrong for calling the link of an id

Comment: if I replace my last line with this one then clicking on the map marker correctly takes me to the property details page of the sidelisting with id of 3: `$('#3 a').click();`

Comment: so how do I replace the `#3` with: `$('sidelisting with same id as the index of this marker a').click();

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out, I was getting a couple of things wrong, here's the working code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerArray[i], 'click', function(){
         var index = markerArray.indexOf(this);
         $('#' + index + ' a').click();
});
```

I didn't know I had to construct the selector within the `$()` that way with the plus signs and the space before the a tag is also required